# Time based filter and forwarding

Tags: google-apps-script, google-voice

I use google voice for my business. I need to be able to forward the voicemail's to my secretary when she is working in the mornings. I have the option to just send her a copy of every voicemail that comes in but i only want to send her the ones that come in while she is working.

Is there a script I can write to place all emails from a certain email address between 9am and 1pm in a filter, and then just setup forwarding to only forward that filter?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can actually accomplish this without a script with a service such as [ifttt](https://ifttt.com/) (if **this** then **that**) with a few simple clicks. Free services like ifttt can integrate your web services or automate tasks on your behalf. I'm a big fan of automation for productivity's sake.

Although you can solve this need with a script it would likely be faster and easier to use an existing service like ifttt (although plenty of others exist). With ifttt your "recipe would like:

- if: "GMAIL: New email in inbox from search"
- possible Gmail search terms include terms such as older_than,
  newer_than and [many more](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)
- then: fwd email to secretary

If you do actually want to solve it with apps script, I can give you some pointers so that you can code it yourself!